# Best way of organising connection between server and clients in LAN?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, network-programming

We have an android app that on one particular device acts like a server. And all the other devices act like clients.

Server is starting to listen for incoming tcp connections in while loop. When connection request received it fires an event, so the user of this class can handle request and then call WriteData method of the MyTcpServer class to respond to income request. Then networkStream of connected client is closed and new iteration of loop is started.

Is it a good practice to receive incoming requests in a while loop and then to close it after sending data to client?

A server and clients use the same class listed below:

```
public class MyTcpServer
{
    #region Fields

    TcpListener listener;
    TcpClient client;

    #endregion 

    #region Properties 

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Protected methods

    protected static byte[] StringToBytes(string input)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    public void Start(string SERVER_IP, int PORT_NO)
    {
        if (IsRunning)
            return;
        IsRunning = true;

        Task.Run (() => {

            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse (SERVER_IP);

            listener = new TcpListener (localAdd, PORT_NO);
            Console.WriteLine ("Listening...");
            listener.Start ();

            while (true) {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient ();
                //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream ();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                //---read incoming stream---
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read (buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                //---convert the data received into a string---
                string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString (buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                var ip = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString ();

                Array.Clear (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine ("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString ("HH:mm:ss") + "] Received : " + dataReceived);

                DataReceived?.Invoke (this, new Data () {Stream = nwStream, Message = dataReceived,
                    IP = ip
                });

                nwStream.Close();
            }
        });
    }

    public void WriteData(NetworkStream nwStream, byte[] responseData)
    {
        try {
            nwStream.Write (responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine (e.ToString ());
        }
    }

    public void WriteData(string ip, int port, byte[] data)
    {
        try {
            var client = new TcpClient (ip, port);
            var nwstream = client.GetStream ();
            nwstream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
            nwstream.Close ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine (e.ToString ());
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (client != null)
            client.Close ();
        listener.Stop ();
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    #endregion

    public event EventHandler<Data> DataReceived;

    public class Data
    {
        public NetworkStream Stream {get;set;}
        public string Message {get;set;}
        public string IP {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how basic (and now old-fashioned) HTTP works. The client (browser) connects to the server (web-server), send a request, reads the response and then the server closes the connection. Now days there's things like "keep-alive" that keeps the connection alive in case more requests needs to be made, since the connection handshake is comparatively big in TCP, so if a client is supposed to make more that a couple of requests within a couple of seconds, it might be useful to keep the connection alive for a while, or let the client close when done.

Comment: Can an android device survive keep-alive connections in case of too many clients (like 200) ? Will it have to create separate thread for each such connection (or maybe two for read/write). The data that needs to be transmitted it's lightweight, and only needs to be sent to clients when server data updated.

Comment: I would use WebSocket which is TCP Duplex , you can have List of clients.
There are couple of framework for for WebSocket in .net , google it